# epoch time with decimals is wrong

Tags: php, epoch

A third party API is outputting: "1373762187.198" as a valid date time.

When passed through PHPs date function, I get todays date even though I know the object its attached to is over a week old.

Any ideas how todo a correct conversation?

Comment: [Works for me](http://3v4l.org/B09kU)

Comment: Hey thanks man, it turns out the third party API output is funky and I wasnt noticing the patterns. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just strip the decimals away with an integer cast and then pass it to `date` (or do you need the milliseconds?)

```
date("...", (int)$date);
```

Comment: Who cares about [casting ints](http://ideone.com/RRgMh2) ?